# Phalcon and Angular JS routing - use Angular templates and Phalcon controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phalcon, angular-routing

I am using Phalcon with Angular JS and have the problem, that Phalcon is catching all my Angular routes. The target is that the route /dashboard is called first which loads the Angular, jQuery, etc. If the user clicks on the link /people only the ng-view should change and the Angular template should be loaded.

Volt template:

```
<div ng-app="sampleApp">

    // Loads menu with two links to /dashboard and /people
    <?php $this->partial("partials/navigation") ?>

    <?php echo $this->flashSession->output(); ?>

    <div ng-view ng-controller="DashboardController">
    {{ content() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

My target is that when the user clicks a link only the ng-view is changed with the routes defined in Angular:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardController'
        }).when('/people', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/people.html',
            controller: 'PeopleController'
        });
```

Instead of that the Phalcon routing tries to load the "PeopleController" with the method "indexAction".

I have tried to disable the Phalcon routing and only load the dashboard route (where the Angular library is loaded):

```
$di->set('router', function () {

    $router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);

    $router->add("/dashboard", array(
        'controller' => 'dashboard',
        'action' => 'index'
    ));

    return $router;
});
```

How can I load some pages/routes with Phalcon like the /dashboard and some pages/routes to change the ng-view in Angular?

Best regards,
Patrick

Edit: It works fine with the normal Angular, but with activated HTML mode it makes problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing your router passing `false` as parameter would be enough to not add the default routes. Only the ones you explicitly add will be matched.

However your problems are more likely coming from your client-side router. Please read carefully about the [**$location service**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) to understand how make angular be able to tell if the current route should be retrieved from your server or not.

I would like to improve this answer if you provide more details about your angular router setup.